# Magento Checkout Small Error

Tags: css, magento, checkout

I'm having some problems related to the design of the magento checkout process on Internet Explorer.
When the first-step is correctly completed and the "Continue" button is clicked, some elements from the first-step form still remain visible even though the div that contains them has the styles set to `display:none`.

I have no idea why this is happening, can any of you [take a look](http://www.tapet-online.ro) ? You need to try and order something and go to the checkout process and try to get by the first step.

The problem appears only on IE 8 & 9, cause I restricted older versions on this website.

All the best!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First check your tags. I think the li tag is not closed properly.

```
It's showing </li/> for the <li id="opc-billing" class="allow"> opening tag.
```

Which is obviously wrong.

If checking that doesn't work, then try giving the style

> overflow:hidden

to the

```
<li> or the DIV
```

inside it.

I think that will work.

Comment: To be honest, I don't have any idea why it is rendered wrongly in IE. On the other browsers the code appears to be correct. That's the big problem I'm having, IE is rendering the code different and I can't see the reason why it's happening so.
I also tried to add `overflow:hidden` to the div, but nothing changed. Those elements were still appearing when they should've been hidden.

Comment: try to give the display:none and overflow:hidden !important. You can try some IE hacks too